# Language of the tags #2

Tags: discussion, tags

Результат [цього обговорення](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/4) виглядає так, що більшість підтримує ідею мати таги **обома** мовами (щоб таги однієї мови були посиланнями на / синонімами до тагів іншої мови).

Але [відповідь з найбільшою кількістю голосів](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10/4) в тій дискусії не говорила чітко про те, теги якою мовою мають бути первинними.

Тепер, за порадою bytebuster'а, час вирішити, **яка мова має бути основною для тегів:**

- **Англійські теги основні, українські посилаються на них.**
- **Українські теги основні, англійські посилаються на них.**

Технічні зауваження:

- Під час введення тегів при створенні питання тегова автопідказка працює як для основних назв тегів, так і для вторинних.
  <sup>Ви можете подивитися як це працює, наприклад, [тут](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), вводячи "op" чи "opp" в полі "Tags" — вилізе підказка "antonyms (also: opposite-word)" (тільки не треба створювати тестові питання там, я запропонував подивитися лише як саме поле "Tags" працює).</sup>
  Тобто вибір первинної мови тегів не дуже впливає на процес *створення* питання.
- Але при перегляді створеного питання видимі лише первинні назви тегів.
  <sub>Наприклад, навіть якщо автор [цього](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/98300/5811) використовував при його створенні тег "opposite-word", в фінальному варіанті все одно видимий "antonyms".</sub>
  Таким чином вибір первинної мови тегів впливає на те, як виглядатиме створене питання.

Переваги первинної англійської:

- Це пасує до мови інтерфейсу користувача (ну тобто ми ж маємо пункт "Ask Question" в меню, а не "Поставити питання").

  До речі та трішки не за темою:

  > Як я знаю, Stack Exchange не дозволяє мати користувацький інтерфейс не англійською.
  >
  > Але можливо роздобити розширення (add-on'и) для Firefox і Google Chrome, що локалізуватимуть користувацький інтерфейс локально через UserScript. Звісно, таке рішення далеке від ідеалу: (а) це працює лише на ПК (не на мобілках, наприклад; і навіть не на всіх веб-оглядачах для ПК); та й (б) сам факт, що користувачу треба інсталлювати add-on не дуже приємний. Проте це можливо; и теоретично таких add-on міг би локалізувати й теги теж, якщо потрібно.
  >
  > Звісно, це досить неідеальне рішення, але варто було про це сказати.
- Зараз більшість тегів англійською. Я не знаю дуже багато про цей процес, але мегі знається, що в такому випадку створення українських посилань на англійські теги буде простішим, ніж створення англійських посилань на українські теги. Тому що щоб запропонувати створення посилання/синоніма для тега *А*, потрібна не лише певна загальна «репутація», а й певний «score» в межах тега *А*. В межех англійських тегів багато з нас вже мають певний «score» (до речі, чи хтось знає, як подивитися цей самих «score» в межах якогось тега?) — але жоден з нас не має «score» в межах українських тегів (бо більшість з них просто ще не створені).
- Мені знається, українцю якось легше все ж таки призвичаїтися до англійських тегів, ніж англійцю до українських..

Переваги первинної української:

- Ну, банально більшість відвідувачів, особливо на початку — українці.

Власне зараз я вже більше схиляюся до первинної англійської для тегів — але мені майже однаково (50%/50%).

<sub>P.S.: Перепрошую за одруки, трішки втомлений зараз.</sub>

*Доповнення:* Ще маленьке питаннячко — якому формату слід надавати перевагу в настанові-щодо-використання (usage guidance) для кожного тегу:

- Англійською, потім українською («This tag is for …. Цей тег для ….»).
- Українською, потім англійською («Цей тег для …. This tag is for ….»).

---

The result of [that discussion](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/4) looked like the common opinion is to have tags **in both languages** (with tags of one language being aliased to tags of another language).

Still, [the vote-leading answer](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10/4) in that discussion was quite unclear in what language of tags should be the primary.

Now, per bytebuster's suggestion, it's time to decide what language is to be the first:

- **English tags are primary, Ukrainian tags are aliases to them.**
- **Ukrainian tags are primary, English tags are aliases to them.**

Technical notes:

- When filling tags during creation a question, auto-completion of tags works *both* for primary names and aliases.
  <sub>You can see how it works it, for example, [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) by typing "op" or "opp" in the "Tags" field — "antonyms" a.k.a. "opposite-word" will arise (no need to actually create a question there, I proposed just to test the "Tags" field).</sub>
  So, choice of the primary language doesn't affect *creation* a question too much.
- Still, the created question will show *only* the primary tag name.
  <sub>For example, even if a questioner had chosen a "opposite-word" tag during creating of [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/98300/5811) question — it anyway is displayed as "antonyms" in its final state.</sub>
  So choice of the primary language affects *final look* of the question a lot.

Pros of using English as primary:

- It's is consistent with the language of user interface (i.e. we have "Ask Question" menu item, not "Поставити питання").

  BTW and a bit off-topic:

  > As far as I know, Stack Exchange does not allow to have non-English user-interface.
  >
  > Still it's possible to develop Firefox and Chrome addons that will translate user-interface locally on user machine via userscript. Of course, such a solution is quite far from ideal: (a) it works only on PCs (not mobile phones, for example; and even non all PC web-browsers would be supported); and (b) requires user to install a browser add-on. Still, it's possible; and such add-on could translate tags too, if needed.
  >
  > Of course, it's quite no-ideal solution, but I had to say about it.
- Currently most of tags are English. I don't know about that a lot, but I suppose that creating Ukrainian aliases to English tags would need much less effort. Because to propose an alias for tag *A*, you need to have not only certain level of total reputation, but also a certain score within the tag *A*. Within English tags many of us already have some score (BTW, does anybody knows how can I look by score within a specific tag?) — but none of us have score within Ukrainian tags (because most of them even don't exist yet).
- It seems to require less efforts from Ukrainian-speaker to learn English tags than to require Ukrainian tags.

Pros of using Ukrainian as primary:

- Well, most of visitors, especially in the very beginning would be Ukrainian.

Actually, currently I even tend more to English primary tags — but I don't really care about it.

<sub>P.S.: Sorry for typos, I'm a bit tired right now.</sub>

*Addition:* Another tiny question — what format should we prefer in a usage guidance for every tag:

- English, then Ukrainian (“This tag is for …. Цей тег для ….”).
- Ukrainian, then English (“Цей тег для …. This tag is for ….”).

Answer (score 5):

Ще раз запощу свій коментар до [цієї відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10/69).

> Targeting primarily English audience is bad for this site, because we have an example of two russian sites here. The one targeting English audience is now 1700 days in beta and there is no signs that it will ever go to non-beta state (because English speakers rarely ask questions). It's counterpart targeting native speakers looks like it has beaten all the goals for the beta stage (it has no Area 51 stats page) - the only issue there is moderation.
>   <sub>(it was initially created on other platform and had no proper moderation).</sub>

І ще один коментар від @Giles:

> This is the policy we follow on French Language. All visible tags should be in French, with a synonym in English. Moderators create the synonyms as we notice new tags. Spanish Language and Portuguese Language follow the same policy. I think the other language sites use English tags with other-language synonyms, or English-only tags.

Навіть зараз питання йдуть переважно українською мовою, думаю що для багатьох українські теги будуть більш прийнятні. Особливо коли наш сайт почне видаватися у результатах Google і з'явится аудиторія що не знайома із StackExchange (і не буде вже такої переваги людей що добре знають англійську).

Доречі та сама відповідь пропонує українські теги з англійськими синонімами і отримала найбільше (9) голосів підтримки. Думаю це досить сильний аргумент на користь українських тегів.

Щодо score - він розповсюджується на синоніми, тож тут немає за що переживати.

Щодо відповідності тегів мові інтерфейсу - мені здається що краще локалізувати те що можна локалізувати ніж просто залишати все англійською. Тим більше, якщо більшість питань будуть українською то до українських текстів краще пасуватимуть українські теги.

Comment: Я там трішки доповнив питання — хоча, я припускаю, що для цього підпитання Ви оберете аналогічне рішення.

Comment: Авжеж :) Експеримент показав що опис тегу один на всі синоніми, тож я пропоную спочатку українську версію писати.